# Laravel 7 middleware 'except' rule not working in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

If logged in I want to block the `/dashboard/login` address.
If logout I want to allow access to `/dashboard/login` address

The code I wrote is not working.
How can I solve this problem for Laravel 7.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/dashboard/', 'DashboardController@home')->middleware('admin');
Route::get('/dashboard/login', 'DashboardController@login')->name('dashboard_login');
Route::post('dashboard/post-login','DashboardController@postLogin');
```

**DashboardController**

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['dashboard_login']]);
    }
    public function home(){
       return view('dashboard.home');
    }
    public function login(){
       return view('dashboard.login');
    }

  }
```

**Admin Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() &&  (auth()->user()->role == 1 or auth()->user()->role == 2)){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('home')->with('error',"You don't have admin access.");
    }
}
```

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` there you can check the middleware associated with it

Comment: `->middleware('admin')->middleware('admin')` why...

Comment: @Berto99 I wrote it by mistake. But it's not a problem with it.

Comment: @bhucho According to the `php artisan route:list` result `middware:web`

Comment: @Nasimba ok, the routes obviously can't see the middleware since it's on the controller, not on the route

Comment: Follow one consistent style. Either middleware on routes or inside a controller. Also, you just want to accomplish this in controller or anywhere is fine. What if middleware codes have bug?

Comment: If you exclude 'auth' middlware from 'dashboard_login' nothing will be blocked or redirected. Only thing you achieve is, that 'dashboard_login' is accessible without middleware at all...

Comment: @nice_devThe reason to use the current solution is because I don't know the correct way. What is the correct method? What should I do .

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I don't know how to fix the problem. What should I do for you? What is the most efficient and correct way?

Comment: Well, show your middleware codes first? Just cross checking if there is any issue there.

Comment: @nice_dev I shared the content of admin middleware.user role 1==super admin,role 2= =admin,role 3==normal user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i thought of this options

web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@home')->middleware('auth','admin'); //if not logged , redirect to auth default login then if logged, AdminMiddleware checking role
```

DashboardController:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function home(){
       return view('dashboard.home');
    }

    public function login(){
       if(auth()->check())
          return redirect()->route('or url where you want to redirect if user already logged');
       return view('dashboard.login');
    }

}
```

if you still want to check middleware in DashboardController, forget about web.php, then

DashboardController:

```
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('auth')->except('login');
       //here what u asked, you can remove middleware in route
       //$this->middleware('admin')->only('home');
    }
    public function home(){
       return view('dashboard.home');
    }

    public function login(){
       if(auth()->check())
          return redirect()->route('or url where you want to redirect if user already logged');
       return view('dashboard.login');
    }

}
```

Comment: you used ```middleware('auth','admin');``` .Is it possible to use it in controller __construct ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to switch from

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['dashboard_login']]);
```

to

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except('login');
```

by the looks of things on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: Nothing changed.Disabled when session is closed, access allowed when open.

Comment: except() variables are the function name e.g: except('login');

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use the 'guest' Middleware.

```
Route::get('/dashboard/login', 'DashboardController@login')->middlware('guest')->name('dashboard_login');
```

If authenticated, the user gets redirected to a defined route.

The behaviour can be adjusted in *app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php*